# Rundeck Plugin to validate values before job execution

Tags: rundeck

We would like to validate option values with a http request before the job executes.
I created a ExecutionLifecyclePlugin with Java and hooked in the 'beforeJobStarts' and return a new ExecutionLifecycleStatus with "isSeccessful = false" if a certain value is set.

```
if (key.equals("test") && value.equals("asdf")) {

    return new ExecutionLifecycleStatus() {
        @Override
        public boolean isSuccessful() {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public  String getErrorMessage() {
            return "value already exists";
        }
    };
}
```

But the behavior is not as expected, the job behavior as if the job run failes. The user can not change the field and send it again. The form should not submit and show the error message.
I seems this plugin is not usefull for input validation.

Should we use a UI Plugin or is there a better option for validating the fields egains an external http function before execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your goal you need the JobLifeCycle plugin (not the ExecutionLifecycle Plugin), check the official documentation [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/developer/job-lifecycle.html). You need to use the `beforeJobExecution` method.

Check the example [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/tree/main/examples/example-java-job-lifecycle-plugin). And, the `beforeJobExecution` method usage [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/blob/main/examples/example-java-job-lifecycle-plugin/src/main/java/org/rundeck/example/plugin/ExampleJobLifecyclePlugin.java#L54).

Comment: it would be nice if this plugin would be part here: in the plugin bootstraper https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/learning/howto/plugin-bootstrap.html

Comment: the plugin works. sad that it's throwing an exception.
Any chance that we modify the remove the next before the message from the plugin: `Job could not start due to the following errors: Error dispatcing event [PRE_EXECUTION] for component [CustomValidation]: already in use` we would like to show only `already in use`